# Squarespace collection page has a different css that I can't find to edit

Tags: css, squarespace

I am currently using Squarespace to build a website (http://www.aspect11.com.au/) and I am injecting code to style it in a specific way. The 'collection' page (a gallery) is not displaying like the other pages though (Contact) and I can't figure out how to make it display the same.

Can someone please use Inspect Code (or something similar) and provide so suggestions? I would really appreciate it.

The current css I have customised is as follows:

```
/* Home Bg */
#siteWrapper{
background-    image:url('http://static1.squarespace.com/static/52dcef2ae4b086a63887d86f/t/54dd3d    a2e4b0977f1c7ca66e/1423785392011/Melbourne-Property-Photography-1.jpg');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
-webkit-background-size:cover;
-moz-background-size:cover;
-o-background-size:cover;
background-size:cover;
background-position:center;}

/* header div top */
.transparent-header.view-list .banner-thumbnail-wrapper, .transparent-header.collection-type-page .banner-thumbnail-wrapper {
padding: 180px 0 155px;
height: 50px
}

/* Gallery and contact page header */
body:not(.has-banner-image).transparent-header #header, .collection-type-gallery.has-banner-image.transparent-header #header {
 background-color: #3f3131;
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(63,49,49,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(63,49,49,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(255,255,255,0))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(63,49,49,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(63,49,49,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(63,49,49,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(63,49,49,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#3f3131', endColorstr='#00ffffff',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}

/* Dropdown nav */
#headerNav nav .subnav, #sidecarNav nav .subnav {
opacity: 0.6;
filter: alpha(opacity=60); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}  

/* #siteWrapper {
background-image:     url("https://static1.squarespace.com/static/52dcef2ae4b086a63887d86f/t/54e15da8e4b033d521c9f341/1424055721678/Logo-pattern.jpg") !important;
background-repeat: repeat;
}*/
/* Prefooter */
#preFooter {
background-color: #4c3e3e;
-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
opacity: 0.0;
filter: alpha(opacity=00); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
.pre-footer-inner .sqs-layout {
padding: 0px;
}

/* Footer */
#footer {
background-color: #3f3131;
-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
opacity: 0.0;
filter: alpha(opacity=0); /* For IE8 and earlier */

 }
.footer-inner {
padding: 9px 9px;
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
}

/* background for pages */
#content {
background-image: url("https://static1.squarespace.com/static/52dcef2ae4b086a63887d86f/t/54e15da8e4b033d521c9f341/1424055721678/Logo-pattern.jpg") !important;
background-repeat: repeat;
}
/* background for gallery */
#page {
 background-image:     url("https://static1.squarespace.com/static/52dcef2ae4b086a63887d86f/t/54e15da8e4b033d521c9f341/1424055721678/Logo-pattern.jpg") !important;
background-repeat: repeat;}

/* About company heading styles */
.desc-wrapper p {
font-family: "proxima-nova","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
font-weight: 400;
font-size: 16px;
letter-spacing: 0px;
text-transform: none;
line-height: 1.5em;
font-family: "futura-pt";
font-size: 24px;
line-height: 1.3em;
text-transform: uppercase;
letter-spacing: 4px;
font-weight: 300;
font-style: normal;
color: #ECECEC;
margin: 20px auto;
-webkit-transform: translatez(0);
}

h2 {
font-family: "proxima-nova","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
font-weight: 500;
font-family: "futura-pt";
font-size: 45px;
line-height: 1.2em;
text-transform: none;
font-style: normal;
color: #FFF;
}

h2, .summary-title a {
color: #FFF;
}

h3 {
font-family: "proxima-nova","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
letter-spacing: 0px;
text-transform: none;
font-family: "futura-pt";
line-height: 1.3em;
text-transform: uppercase;
letter-spacing: 4px;
font-weight: 500;
font-style: normal;
color:#FFF
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On the `#siteWrapper` id, you need to add the following at the end:

`background-attachment:fixed;`

That will make the background image act the same as the homepage background.

**UPDATE**
To make it look like the Contact page, you'll need to change a few more things. This should do the trick:

On the `#page` id, comment out or delete `max-width:1020px`.

Add the following to `#content`:

```
margin:0 auto;
max-width:1020px;
```

Comment: That worked perfectly but now how do I expand the white background to the full width of the page on this page? http://www.aspect11.com.au/photographs/

Comment: Worked perfectly - thanks for taking the time to help me :-) http://www.aspect11.com.au/photographs/